# Wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) in default scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I keep getting the error `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)` for my `default_scope` which is `default_scope { where("#{table_name}.tenant_id IS NULL") }`

It keeps giving me this error and I don't understand why.  I have the default scope in my users model.

**Update:**

Error output if using rails console:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
    from /home/evan/Apps/demo-application/app/models/user.rb:18:in `hash'
    from /home/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/scoping.rb:64:in `value_for'
    from /home/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/per_thread_registry.rb:40:in `public_send'
    from /home/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/per_thread_registry.rb:40:in `block in method_missing'
    from /home/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/scoping/default.rb:123:in `ignore_default_scope?'
    from /home/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/scoping/default.rb:134:in `evaluate_default_scope'
    from /home/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/scoping/default.rb:110:in `build_default_scope'
    from /home/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:554:in `with_default_scope'
    from /home/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:582:in `exec_queries'
    from /home/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:471:in `load'
    from /home/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:220:in `to_a'
    from /home/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:573:in `inspect'
    from /home/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /home/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /home/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
```

The `hash` is in my user model as below.

```
 def User.new_remember_token
     SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
 end

 def User.hash(token)
     Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
 end

 private

     def create_remember_token
         self.remember_token = User.hash(User.new_remember_token)
     end
```

Error output if using rails server:

```
ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (0 for 1):
  activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/scoping.rb:70:in `set_value_for'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/per_thread_registry.rb:40:in `block in method_missing'
  activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/scoping/default.rb:127:in `ignore_default_scope='
  activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/scoping/default.rb:140:in `ensure in evaluate_default_scope'
  activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/scoping/default.rb:140:in `evaluate_default_scope'
  activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/scoping/default.rb:110:in `build_default_scope'
  activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/relation.rb:554:in `with_default_scope'
  activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/relation.rb:582:in `exec_queries'
  activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/relation.rb:471:in `load'
  activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/relation.rb:220:in `to_a'
  activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:316:in `find_take'
  activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:66:in `take'
  activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:49:in `find_by'
  activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/querying.rb:6:in `find_by'
  app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:16:in `current_user'
  app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:19:in `signed_in?'
```

And the relevant rails methods:

```
def ignore_default_scope? # :nodoc:
     ScopeRegistry.value_for(:ignore_default_scope, self)
end

def ignore_default_scope=(ignore) # :nodoc:
     ScopeRegistry.set_value_for(:ignore_default_scope, self, ignore)
end
```

Comment: Try this >> default_scope where("#{table_name}.tenant_id IS NULL")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid overwriting Ruby core methods like [`Object#hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-hash), also considering that `Object#hash` is an essential method in Ruby. From the docs:

> Generates a Fixnum hash value for this object. This function must have
>   the property that a.eql?(b) implies a.hash == b.hash.
>
> The hash value is used along with eql? by the Hash class to determine
>   if two objects reference the same hash key. Any hash value that
>   exceeds the capacity of a Fixnum will be truncated before being used.
>
> The hash value for an object may not be identical across invocations
>   or implementations of ruby. If you need a stable identifier across
>   ruby invocations and implementations you will need to generate one
>   with a custom method.

If you really have to overwrite core methods you should *guarantee their functionality* and  *do not change their arguments*: you will get unexpected behaviours all over your app otherwise, like the error you're referring.

Comment: I was just following the rails tutorial to build my own session manager.  As per http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#code-before_create_remember_token

Comment: He made a mistake, probably he is not aware of the `Object#hash` method either. You can [contact him](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/contact) reporting my answer, likely he will fix the tutorial.

Comment: After some research at the very last chapter he changes it to .encrypt, I changed .hash to .encrypt and it worked!  Here's where I found the change:  http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/supplement?version=3.2#sec-encrypted_remember_tokens

Comment: You should contact him, so he can fix it; that tutorial is a very popular tutorial, it should not have this kind of errors.

Comment: The tutorial has just been fixed! Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have not such a variable or method as `table_name`

I think this will work:

```
table name = "users"
default_scope { where("#{table_name}.tenant_id IS NULL") }
```

Also it is cleaner to use [callable objects](http://hackingbit.com/2012/12/02/ruby-closures-blocks-the-callable-objects/) for scopes (they are waiting for it), so it is better to use lambda here:

```
table name = "users"
default_scope ->{ where("#{table_name}.tenant_id IS NULL") }

# or old syntax: 
default_scope lambda { where("#{table_name}.tenant_id IS NULL") }
```

Comment: I put a `logger.info table_name` right before the default scope and it showed users.  I tried with and without the lambda scope and it isn't working.  I updated with the output.