# Paperclip Rails error when trying to refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

My User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :profile => "200x200>", :collab => "300x200>", :msg => "50x50>" }, :default_url => "missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  ...
```

I have just added the :msg and :profile styles and I'm trying to refresh them so they show up properly in my views.

I've tried running:

```
rake paperclip:refresh CLASS=User
```

and I get this error:

```
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
/home/rails/cs480/app/models/user.rb:44:in `hash'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/paperclip-4.1.1/lib/paperclip/attachment_registry.rb:42:in `names_for'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/paperclip-4.1.1/lib/paperclip/attachment_registry.rb:16:in `names_for'
/home/rails/cs480/lib/tasks/paperclip.rake:15:in `obtain_attachments'
```

Here's line 44 of user.rb (not sure why this has anything to do with paperclip)

```
def User.hash(token)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
end
```

I was trying to add an avatar following railstutorial.org.

EDIT: Also, in all my views where I'm trying to display the avatar, it's displaying ":msg" even if I'm trying to display one of the other two. I.E.,

```
<%= image_tag user.avatar.url(:profile) %>
```

is showing the 50x50 avatar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first issue, from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23125219/wrong-number-of-arguments-0-for-1-in-default-scope)

You shouldn't override ruby core methods like [object#hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-hash) they are made for specific reasons and changing their behavior could cause unexpected results , apparently [later](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/supplement?version=3.2#sec-encrypted_remember_tokens) on the tutorial this will change to:

```
def User.digest(token)
  Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
end
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Don't know how I missed that. I can now run paperclip:refresh, and it appears to be refreshing the image but it still is showing the small thumbnail for some reason. I should be able to figure it out from here though. EDIT: It was in my custom css, duh.